# unicode string formatting

Tags: python

I just saw this in a piece of uncommented code.  Is there ever a reason to do this?

```
 new_var = u'%s' % (child.tag)
```

where child is an instance and tag is an attribute of that instance?  It seems like this does it more simply:

```
 new_var = unicode(child.tag)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are identical, and it's just a matter of preference.  In terms of the Zen of Python and such, there's really not a "better" way as both are explicit in that they are getting a unicode representation of `child.tag`.  Mechanically they do the same thing:

```
>>> class foo(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __str__(self):
        return "str: %s" % self.val
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "unicode: %s" % self.val


>>> f = foo("bar")
>>> u'%s' % f
u'unicode: bar'
>>> unicode(f)
u'unicode: bar'
>>> '%s' % f
'str: bar'
```

Answer (score 2):

One reason for this could be either that the code used to contain a literal string which had to be translated (then `%s` is a useful placeholder), or is expected to contain a literal at some later point.

Answer (score 1):

They should produce the same results.  I think the 'u' prefix character wasn't added until Python 2.5 and the unicode() function was there prior to that, and now.  Also, if you need to specify the encoding type, unicode() will let you do that.